# Stripe Payment API with Customer and Card ID

Tags: stripe-payments, strip

In my application, I have Customer ID and Saved Card ID, as Stripe don't return the card number completely(returns more like last 4 digits) I'm unable to pay through the saved card. So suggest the API where it takes Customer and Card ID and proceeds for Payment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a charge using a saved card, simply pass the customer ID (`"cus_..."`) in the [`customer`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge-customer) parameter in your [charge creation request](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge).

If the customer has more than one saved card and you want to charge a non-default card, you can also pass the card ID (`"card_..."`) in the [`source`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge-source) parameter.

You can find a simple tutorial about creating customer objects and using them to create charges [here](https://stripe.com/docs/charges#saving-credit-card-details-for-later).